# Use FFT fft() to compute a Riemann sum

Tags: r, fft

I would like to calculate the Following Sum by applying Fast Fourier transforms (FFT). I want to compute the following Riemann sum approximation using FFT :

[image]
Here is the Psy function that I'm using :

```
Psyfun<-function(u,T,r,q,sigma,lmbda,meanV,v0,rho){
  j  <- as.complex(1i)
  a <- lmbda*meanV
  b <- lmbda
  d <- sqrt((j*rho*sigma*u-b)**2+(u**2+j*u)*sigma**2)
  g <- (b-j*rho*sigma*u-d)/(b-j*rho*sigma*u+d)
  ret <- exp(j*u*(r-q)*T)
  ret <- ret*exp((a/sigma**2)*((b - rho*j*sigma*u - d)*T - 2.0*log((1-g*exp(-d*T))/(1-g))))
  return (ret*exp((v0/sigma**2)*(b - rho*j*sigma*u - d)*(1-exp(-d*T))/(1-g*exp(-d*T))))
}
```

Here are the sample parameters :

```
r = 0.025 ,q= 0.01, sigma = 0.2, lmbda = 0.5, meanV = 0.5, v0 = 0.5 , rho = 0.3
```

I want to compute the values for  K and T equals to :

K1=172.77 and T1 = 0.197, K2= 75.63  and T2 = 0.563,  K3 = 269.54  and T3 = 0.2648

I implement the following code to do it:

```
  N=2^10           # Number of subdivision in [0,a]
  alpha=2          # alpha 
  delta= 0.25      # delta= a/N  where a is the up value of w (w in [0,a])
  lambda=(2*pi)/(N*delta)
  j=seq(1,N,1)
  k=seq(1,N,1)
  b=(lambda*N)/2
  strike= -b+(k-1)*lambda
  strike= exp(strike)
  res=c()
  for (i in 1:N){
    w=delta*(i-1)      #  w= j*delta but from 1 to N so w=(i-1)*delta
    w_FC=w-(alpha+1)*1i
    phi= Psyfun(w_FC,T,r,q,sigma,lmbda,meanV,v0,rho)
    phi=phi*exp(-r1*(T))
    phi=phi/(alpha^2+alpha-w^2+1i*(2*alpha+1)*w)
    phi=phi*delta*exp(1i*w*b)
    res=rbind(res,phi)
  }  
  Result=Re(fft(res))*exp(-alpha*(-b+(k-1)*lambda))/pi
```

I obtain k numbers of values so how to get the one that correspond to K1,K2,K3.
Can anybody recommend a procedure to implement the computation? Thanks

I have no previous experience in Fast Fourier transforms (FFT) processing, so I appreciate any tips and pointers related to the mathematics / methods / Code in addition to advice on how better to approach this programmatically.

Comment: And why don't you use `fft()`?

Comment: I want to use fft() but how to use it?

Comment: I add the code that I used to compute it using fft(), I think it works but how to select the value that correspond to the specific K1,K2...